# Finding the maximum number of members in the math club.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics

I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198175/find-the-sum-of-all-possible-values-of-m) few days ago which was from a local math contest in my city. The question and the solution seems interesting to me and I am interested in solving the generalization of the problem. So, the generalized problem is as follows:

> Professor Liyung wants to make a math club consisting of his $n$ students. But there is a problem. Each student is enemies with exactly $k$ ($1\leq k \leq n-1$) students. And no one wills to be a member of the club if any of his enemies is already a member of the club. Let $M$ be the maximum number of members the club can have. Find all possible values of $M$. (If student $A$ is an enemy with student $B$, then student $B$ is an enemy with student $A$. Student $A$ is not enemy with himself.)

Here, $n,k$ are given numbers such that they satisfy the conditions of the problem (i.e. it is possible to draw a graph with $n$ vertices each of the vertices having degree $k$). Here are my workings regarding the problem:

### My workings

I first tried for a fixed value of $k$. And I got the following:

- For $k=1$, the problem statement is true for only even $n$. Then, $M$ has only one possible value that is $\frac n 2$.
- [For $k=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198175/find-the-sum-of-all-possible-values-of-m), all values of $M$ are possible in the range $[\lceil\frac n 3\rceil,\lfloor\frac n 2\rfloor]$. (Explanation is in the link.)
- For $k=3$, the upper bound of $M$ is $\lfloor \frac n 3\rfloor$ and the lower bound of $M$ is $\lceil\frac n 4\rceil$. However, I don't have a nice argument to prove the upper bound. The proof of the lower bound is as follows:
  ***Proof:*** If we choose $\lceil\frac n 4\rceil -1$ students as members, then there are at most $3\lceil\frac n 4\rceil -3$ students who can't be members of the club. Then, we can choose at least $1$ students from the remaining students as a member of the club. This proves that $M$ is at least $\lceil\frac n 4\rceil$ for $k=3$.

So, I think all values of $M$ are in $[\lceil\frac{n}{k+1}\rceil,\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor]$. The lower bound can be proved by following the similar steps as in for $k=3$. However, I am unable to show that all values in $[\lceil\frac{n}{k+1}\rceil,\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor]$ can be a value of $M$.

---

I hope my thoughts are correct. I need to complete the solution i.e. proving the upper bound and showing that all values in the stated interval are possible. [The original problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198175/find-the-sum-of-all-possible-values-of-m) involves graph theory in its solution. So, can the generalized problem be solved with graph theory?

Comment: For $k=3, n=6$ we have $M=3$. Also, for $k=3, n=8$ I find $M=4$.

Comment: The upper bound can be n/2 for larger n and fixed k. Take a bipartite k-regular graph. If you don't know what that means, split the students into 2 sets and always draw the enemies between the two sets (not within)

Comment: Why do you use word maximal for $M$. You can just ask what values can $M$ have?

Comment: @Aqua I didn't get your point. $M$ is defined such that it's the maximum number of members the club can have. And I said *Find all possible values of $M$*. As there are more than one values of $M$ for each $k$ and $n$, there exists a maximal $M$ for each case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about the lower bound, but not the upper. The correct upper bound is $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ for any fixed value of $k\leq n/2$.

To see that this is an upper bound, fix a club with $M$ members and count edges of the graph, i.e. pairs who are enemies. There must be $Mk$ pairs with exactly one person in the club (each person in the club has $k$ enemies, none of whom are in the club). There are some number $r\geq 0$ of pairs who are both outside the club. Now everyone not in the club has $k$ enemies, and that gives $(n-M)k$ ordered pairs where the first person is not in the club. This counts each of the $Mk$ pairs with exactly one person in the club once, and each of the $r$ pairs of two non-members twice. So $(n-M)k=2r+Mk$, and since $r\geq 0$ we have $n-M\geq M$.

This bound can be achieved for any even $n$. (If $k$ is odd, then any graph with every vertex having degree $k$ must have $n$ being even.) To see this, start with the complete bipartite graph with both parts having size $n/2$ - every vertex has degree $n/2$. Now remove a perfect matching, which exists by Hall's theorem (a corollary of Hall's theorem is that any regular bipartite graph - unless it is $0$-regular - has a perfect matching). This decreases all degrees by $1$. Keep doing this until every degree is $k$. Clearly either part of the original graph contains no edges, so is a valid club, and has size $n/2$.

Now to obtain anything in between the two bounds, you just need to mix the two constructions. E.g. if $k=3$ and $n=100$ you can get $M=25$ by taking $25$ copies of $K_4$, or $M=50$ by the construction above. To get, say, $M=41$, take $9$ copies of $K_4$ and do the construction above on the remaining $64$ vertices. Your optimal club will then have one person from each $K_4$ and $32$ people from the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

Imitating proof from the link, we have $k\cdot M \geq n-M$ so $M\geq {n\over k+1}$

For the upper bound:

Let $G$ be a graph of students being connected iff they are enemy. Clearly this graph has $\varepsilon ={nk\over 2}$. Suppose set of vertices of this graph can be represented as union of maximal cliques $Q_1,Q_2,...Q_m$. Since we can choose from each clique at most $1$ student we have $M\leq m$. So we need to find the minimum value of $m$. But this now is [Clique Covering Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliqueCoveringNumber.html) problem.

So, if:

- $n=2l+1$ then we can make $l+1$ cliques so we have $M\leq l+1 =  \lfloor {n+1\over 2} \rfloor $.
- $n=2l$ then we can make $l$ cliques so we have $M\leq l =  \lfloor {n\over 2} \rfloor $.